# Download file from "file://" path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know this is quite a noobish question, but i can't figure out why i'm not able to download a file from a "file://" path.

Currently, the application is using Response on a RowCommand event from GridView to achieve this. Because i wanted to change some things in this page, i've tried using WebClient, Ajax or Generic Handlers with no success, as Response wouldn't download the files.

```
string fileName = $"{id}_{code}.pdf";
string filepath = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url.Boleto.Cobranca"].ToString()}{fileName}";

Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(filepath);
```

Can someone explain to me what's the difference between "http" and "file" paths and why i can't download files using async tools?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *difference between "http" and "file"* ig http stands for global protocol whereas file only can access local resources

Comment: Note that it would start `file:///`, i.e. three slashes.

Comment: `file:///` is a file on the local system, the server isn't processing your request.

Comment: @Agent_Orange, thanks for the reply. I know the basic differences, but why other ways of downloading files won't work with file paths? How could i transform a local system path in http?

Comment: @Gusman Is there another way of downloading files from local system?

Comment: How and when you are generating the file? You should upload the file inside the application folder to download it back.

Comment: @Sivaprasath, the file is generated by a WebService and stored on a separate server.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the path correctly, try putting filename in quotes

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```